# php codeigniter how to restrict access to files in a directory using the controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, directory

I wanted to follow up on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050844/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-directorys-files-in-the-browser.) I previously asked which I'm still not able to answer.

To summarize, the goal for `www.mysite.com/uploads` is to have "uploads" double as both a php controller and a directory.

The answer given by user "anonymous" about writing some authentication in the "uploads" controller constructor is what I've tried to do but it is not working yet for me.

I'm returning each content's details including its `src=""` directory location via a controller named "content":

```
/content/account_id# (e.g., 3)/item_id# ((e.g., 2)
```

In the `www.mysite.com/content/3/2` view file, I like to play the content, e.g., a video file, via the aforementioned video tag's `src` attribute. In this case, `src="/uploads/3/2/my_video.m4v"`.

Here's my uploads controller code so far:

```
class Uploads extends CI_Controller {

function Uploads()
{
  parent::__construct();

      $account_id= $this->session->userdata('account_id'); // =3 in this example
      $item_id=$this->uri->segment('3'); // =2 in this example
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('items');
      $this->db->where('account_id, $account_id)->where('item_id, $item_id);
      $query=$this->db->get();

      if(empty($query){ return false; }
      else { return true; }
    }
 }
```

As you can see from the "items" table query, I'm aiming for the scenario where, if a given account_id doesn't own a given item_id, then they don't get access to the indicated "uploads" sub-directory.

However, this code is clearly not doing anything because if anyone, **not** just the user with account_id=3, goes to `www.mysite.com/uploads/3/2/my_video.m4v`, they can still access this video (it is downloaded by Firefox, safari, and played by natively by chrome).

Any thoughts one might have would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrict direct access by using an .htaccess file.

Then you have to create a function in your controller that streams the file via PHP after the user has been authorized.

Comment: hi minboost, i'm not familiar with how to write .htaccess rules, might you be willing to provide some code? thanks!

Comment: There are lots of htaccess files in CI already (check the different folders). You can create a new one, just put `access deny all` in it and that should do it.

Comment: Hi minboost, thanks but adding this "access deny all" in the root of my "uploads" directory denies access to all files in there regardless of what my "content" controller PHP script says. Can you give me a sense of what the PHP should look like to allow authorized users to circumvent this .htaccess command? Are you saying I should make my controller called "uploads" instead? thanks!

Comment: No one should have direct access to any file via the browser. In the controller, you're not redirecting the user to the file location, you are opening the file in PHP and streaming it directly in PHP (and setting the correct response headers too)

Comment: thanks minboost, so to be clear, the code for the "uploads" controller constructor would include checking the DB whether the user has access, and if so setting headers(contentType: 'video/mp4') and calling the fopen('/uploads/3/2/my_video.m4v', 'r') method?

Comment: You got it, although, after you open the file you'll probably need to output it in chunks, since you wouldn't want to read a huge file all at once. Plenty of examples online on how to do this.

Comment: hi minboost, sounds like a plan, thanks again for guiding me down the path! best wishes,